# Prevent overlapping of the chart title and legend with Apache ECharts

Tags: echarts

how can I prevent overlapping of the chart title and legend? Ideally I would like to stack them vertically as it is done in the [echart doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/cheat-sheet.html) .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Title and legend can be moved using their `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` options (and other 'advanced' options described in the [doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend)).

To stack them in your example, just do something like that :

```js
legend: {
  top: 30, // the size of title + margin
  left: 'left' //or 0 or '0%'
}, 
grid: {
  top: 80, // the size of title + legend + margin
},
```

By stacking the title and the legend, the room between them and the chart is a little bit small, that's why I also moved the chart down by a few pixel using the `grid.top` option.

*Note : The value can either be an int representing the pixel value (`0`), a string percentage relative to the container (`'0%'`) or a position (`'left'`).*

Answer (score 0):

```
legend: {
  type: 'scroll'
}
```

This would be an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).